Why am I loosing the focus on my input and do I no longer get suggestions from my autofill service if I click on a button on remote views?
I am developing an autofill service, it is working well if I use simple remote views for suggestions. If I click on one of the remote views suggested, it fills the input of my external application. I still get suggestion whenever I click on the input, so my autofill service keeps working.
However, if I add a button to a remote view, and I click on that button, I no longer get any suggestions from my autofill service. It's like the autofill service is no longer working.
Here is my autoFillRequest funtion, using pending intent.
@Override
public void onFillRequest(FillRequest request, CancellationSignal cancellationSignal, FillCallback callback) {
    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.autofill_suggestion_interactive);
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.value, "Suggested Text");
    remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.icon, R.drawable.ic_autofill);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ButtonActionReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra("EXTRA_INFO", "Additional Info");
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE);

    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.action_button, pendingIntent);

    Dataset dataset = new Dataset.Builder(remoteViews)
        .setValue(findViewById(R.id.autofill_field).getAutofillId(), AutofillValue.forText("Suggested Text"))
        .build();

    FillResponse response = new FillResponse.Builder()
        .addDataset(dataset)
        .build();

    callback.onSuccess(response);
}

And this is the button action receiver:
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String data = intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_INFO");
    AutoDataset dataset =  new Gson().fromJson(data, AutoDataset.class);
    Log.e("ButtonActionReceiver", "info: " + dataset.getPackageName());
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, FloatingDialogService.class);
    serviceIntent.putExtra("EXTRA_DATA", data);
    context.startService(serviceIntent);
}

This opens a floating dialog where I need to put some text, do some execution, and then close it.
After closing the floating popup, I need to get the autofill suggestions again, but I no longer have them. I tried to request the autofill again manually, but it doesn't work.
Below is my approach to call the autofill service again:
From my floating popup, I am calling a broadcast like this:
Intent fillRequestIntent = new Intent("my request to autofill again");
sendBroadcast(fillRequestIntent);
stopSelf(); // Stop the service and remove the floating view

And my broadcast receiver is like this:
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
    if (intent != null && "my request to autofill again".equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Received new fill request broadcast");
        AutoFillServiceImpl myAutofillService = new AutoFillServiceImpl();
        myAutofillService.requestNewFill();

    }
}

Below is the implementation of the requestNewFill function in my autofill service:
@Override
public void onConnected() {
    super.onConnected();
    AppLog.e(TAG, "Autofill Service connected");
}

public void requestNewFill() {
    AppLog.e(TAG, "Request New Fill");
    onCreate();
    onConnected();
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    AppLog.e(TAG, "Autofill Service created");
    mAutoPreferences = AutoPreferences.getInstance(this);
    mUserId = (int) mAutoPreferences.getUserId();
    mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
}

How can I fix this, to get the autofill suggestions again?
